# Jquery title attribute not available after using it for a tooltip

Tags: jquery, tooltip, jquery-tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have a button that is used to update a note. If the user hovers over the button, they will see the text of the note, which is stored in the title. If they click on the button, I want to open a form where the user can update the note.

The problem is, once the button title is used for a tool tip, I can no longer access the title attribute in order to send it to the form.

Below is a simplified version. When the user clicks on the button, the div with id="output" should change to 'button title is "my button"'. What is says is 'button title is ""'.

```
<script>
    $(document).tooltip();

    $(".button-class").click(function() {
        var t = $(this).attr("title");
        $("#output").html('button title is "' + t +'"');
    });    
</script>

<button class="button-class" title="my button">click me</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

The jsfiddle is here : 
http://jsfiddle.net/f844a63f/

If I don't call $(document).tooltip(), it works fine.

Any ideas? I'm using the latest jquery.

Comment: When I debug the jsfiddle page it says tooltip() is undefined. I didn't see jquery ui referenced in your fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :-

```
$(".button-class").click(function() {
   var t = $(this).attr("aria-describedby");    
   var text=$('#'+t).text();
   $("#output").html('button title is "' + text +'"');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/asdasdasdas/f844a63f/1/)

Comment: That seemed to do it. Thank you very much!